# Magento 2.3 : How to create product attribute via declarative schema?

Tags: magento2, setup, declarative-schema

How to create a product attribute in Magento 2.3 via declarative schema. I have tried below code but the input element is not visible on the form.

```
<?php

namespace Rokanthemes\Updates\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class AddAttributes implements DataPatchInterface
{
    protected $_moduleDataSetup;
    protected $_customerSetupFactory;
    protected $_attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->_customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->_attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->_customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->_moduleDataSetup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->_attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'news_from_date', array(
            'type' => Table::TYPE_DATE,
            'label' => 'New from date',
            'input' => 'date',
            'required' => 1,
            'type' => 'static',            
            'visible' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote an entire blog post about this. It is quite extensive and goes into detail about all of the intricacies: https://markshust.com/2019/02/19/create-product-attribute-data-patch-magento-2.3-declarative-schema/

That said, here is the final class of code you can work with:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Foo\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddAlternativeColorAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /** @var EavSetupFactory */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'alternative_color', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Alternative Color',
            'input' => 'select',
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when entering command `bin\magento setup:upgrade`, can you help? question => [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829356/magento-2-3-cant-update-alter-tables-using-declarative-schema)

Comment: how to create multiple attributes at a time? do we need to use different files for each attribute

Comment: @Manjunath to add multiple attributes just keep adding `addAttribute` lines, as many as you need. You can keep them all in the same file/ I typically only separate installer scripts into multiple files if the install script is dealing with two or more completely different concepts.

Comment: that post is far from being "quite extensive"

Comment: @gabrieliri if there is something you didn’t understand or felt was lacking, please do let me know what, and I’ll do my best to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Data patch approch apply after Magento 2.3.x version. So, you can use data patch for add or update data in database table.

You need to create a **CreateCustomAttr.php** file inside **app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Setup/Patch/Data/**

Add this below code inside **CreateCustomAttr.php** file

Reference : https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-create-a-product-attribute-using-data-patches/

```
<?php

declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class CreateCustomAttr implements DataPatchInterface {


    private $moduleDataSetup;


    private $eavSetupFactory;


    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply() {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'news_from_date', [
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'News From Date',
            'input' => 'text',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => '',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies() {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases() {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Moazzam\ProductSeriesAttr\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

/**
 * Create the product attribute for specfic attribute set
 *
 * Class ProductSeriesAttrbute
 */
class ProductSeriesAttrbute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetup
     */
    protected EavSetup $eavSetup;

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    protected ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * ProductSeriesAttr constructor.
     * @param EavSetup $eavSetup
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetup $eavSetup, ModuleDataSetupInterface
                                         $moduleDataSetup)
    {
        $this->eavSetup = $eavSetup;
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    /**
     * Apply the datapatch
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException|\Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $entityTypeId = $this->eavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
        $attributeSetId = $this->eavSetup->getAttributeSetId($entityTypeId, 'Bag');
        $attributeGroupId = $this->eavSetup->getAttributeGroupId(
            $entityTypeId,
            $attributeSetId,
            'Product Details'
        );
        $attributeCode = 'product_series';
        $properties = [
             'type' => 'varchar',
             'label' => 'Product Series',
             'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
             'user_defined' => 1,
            'required' => 0,
             'visible_on_front' => 1,
            'is_used_in_grid' => 1,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => 1
         ];

        $this->eavSetup->addAttribute($entityTypeId, $attributeCode, $properties);
        $this->eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            $entityTypeId,
            $attributeSetId,
            $attributeGroupId,
            $attributeCode
        );
    }
    /**
     * Return the dependencies
     *
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
    /**
     * Return the alisas
     *
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```